# How to ditch single match results in solr query?

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I'm a newbie to solr.

Here is my problem:

When I search `天天爱消除`，my tokenizer will split it to: `天天` & `爱` & `消除`.

I use `disMax` mode, and the query goes like this:

`http://search.dev/solr/collection1/select?q=%E7%88%B1%E6%B6%88%E9%99%A4&defType=dismax&qf=name&wt=json&indent=true&omitHeader=true&rows=500&hl=true&hl.fl=name&hl.simple.pre=<em>&hl.simple.post=<%2Fem>&sort=score+desc`

This would match results like this: `我爱记单词` & `我爱读书`. For me, the relevances of them are to low, so I don't want to show them in the results.

In conclusion, I want to ditch the results that match one term and the term length is 1;

Hope to get some help. Thanks.

---

update:

Need I to set a custom [Collector](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Collector.html)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about having at least 2 term matches from your query , I do not think you need a special collector for this.

You need to use &mm=2 with the rest of your URL/query, here is the documentation with example => http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

If I set mm=2: `At least 2 of the optional clauses must match, regardless of how many clauses there are: "2"`

I think it will also make `天天跑酷` (=> `天天` & `跑酷`) get removed from results.

Am I right?

I just want to remove the results that contains one term match, and that term's length is 1. If it's length > 2, I want to keep it.